# Dataset for Telecom Mobile Tariff Plans

Tags: data-request, telecom

Does anyone know where can I find the dataset for Telecom Mobile plans preferably for Indian telecom service providers?
I need a detailed dataset where there are details of each attribute of tariff.

Comment: The websites of each provider?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The website of telecom provider do not have each and every detail of a tariff plan. For eg, there are NRC (Non-recurring charge) and RC (recurring charge) of every feature. I need dataset which contains this details also